# Add pannel to current class in java

Tags: java, swing, panel

I've created one class `public class SalesFilterPanel extends Panel`. In this class I've created three panels - `private Panel createCustomerPanel()`, `private Panel createDatePanel()`, `private Panel createAmountPanel()`. I want to add these 3 panels to `SalesFilterPanel` class.
My code is:

```
public class SalesFilterPanel extends Panel {

private AppCodeFieldPanel customerField;
JLabel customerNameLabel = new JLabel();
private String custid = null;

private JLabel prodNameLabel;
private AppCodeFieldPanel productField;
private String pid = null;

private AppFormattedTextField amountField;
private AppDateTextFieldPanel dateFromField;
private AppDateTextFieldPanel dateToField;

public SalesFilterPanel() {
    super();
    init();
}

private void init() {
    this.setBorder( BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( "Search Criteria" ) );
    createCustomerPanel();
    createDatePanel();
    createAmountPanel();
    this.add( getComponentPopupMenu() );

}
//here are those 3 method's implementation
}
```

Here how can I add these 3 panels in `SalesFilterPanel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just `add()` the `Panel` to another `Panel`.

Assuming your panel creation methods return `Panel` objects it's just:-

```
 this.add(createCustomerPanel());
```

If you want them in a specific layout, that's a [whole other question](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

Comment: I want to create instance of SalesFilterPanel class into another 'SalesListPanel' class and want to addthat instance to upper panel of the 'SalesListPanel'

Comment: @VilasGalave Then just do for example `Panel upperPanel = new Panel();`, `upperPanel.add(new SalesFilterPanel());`, `frame.add(upperPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);` in the SalesListPanel.

Comment: great...that's perfect. please vote up if my question is good.